# How do you change the background color of Kivy tabs with TabbedPanels?

Tags: python, kivy

I have the below code, and I can't seem to figure out how to change the background color of the tabs in the `TabbedPanel` element, let's say I want them to be red.  Additionally, how would you change the "default" tab when `do_default_tab` is set to false?  Let's say I want Tab 3 to open first when the app is launched.  I've been doing searching but I can't seem to find anything helpful yet...

How would I accomplish these two things?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


Builder.load_string(
    """
<GameScreen>:
    TabbedPanel:
        do_default_tab: False
        size: root.width, root.height

        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Tab 1'
            Label:
                text: 'Screen 1'
        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Tab 2'
            Label:
                text: 'Screen 2'
        TabbedPanelItem:
            text: 'Tab 3'
            Label:
                text: 'Screen 3'
"""
)


class GameScreen(Widget):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.title = 'Test App'
        self.icon = 'return_home/media/icons/test.ico'
        return GameScreen()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the color add `background_color` to predefine the state use `state`:

```
        TabbedPanelItem:
            id: tb1
            state: 'down'
            text: self.state
            background_color: "#30ff00"
            Label:
                text: 'Screen 1'
```

Comment: Wonderful, I thought I had tried this, but evidently not, hah!
Thank you for your help!